# Flex is backing up forever in the specific rule

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

My parser is for assembler, here is [lex](https://bitbucket.org/Pugnator/zcore/src/28c783d1f860c001faed2b44076d3fbc83b42c6f/src/macroasm/z80.lex?at=asm) and [bison](https://bitbucket.org/Pugnator/zcore/src/28c783d1f860c001faed2b44076d3fbc83b42c6f/src/macroasm/asm.y?at=asm) files just in case

in this example all works like a charm:

```
nop
nop
nop
```

Here is debug output

```
--accepting rule at line 154 ("nop")
--accepting rule at line 248 ("
")
--accepting rule at line 154 ("nop")
--accepting rule at line 248 ("
")
--accepting rule at line 154 ("nop")
--accepting rule at line 248 ("
")
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--accepting rule at line 248 ("
")
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--EOF (start condition 0)
```

The problem raise when I try to parse this code (rule is at line 255 in lex file)

```
DEFB    '?'+$80
DEFM    "RN"
DEFB    'D'+$80
```

It backs up forever and looks like it can't reach newline (I have a rule for it).
I generated [backup file](http://pastebin.com/UW8zct3h) from flex, but can't understand how to use it in order to find the root cause.

```
--accepting rule at line 255 ("DEFB")
--accepting rule at line 280 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 280 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 280 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 280 (" ")
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--scanner backing up
--accepting rule at line 105 ("'?'")
--accepting rule at line 233 ("+")
--accepting rule at line 56 ("$80")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backup problem is with your pattern for `char`:

```
ascii             [\x00-\x7F]+
char              '{ascii}{1}'
```

`ascii` can be any number of "ascii" characters; the set includes both newline and apostrophes. Since flex patterns are always greedy, `char` will match from the first <kbd>'</kbd> to the last <kbd>'</kbd>, so the token matched will be:

```
        '?'+$80
DEFM    "RN"
DEFB    'D'
```

It then matches the remaining tokens <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>$80</kbd>.

There is a similar problem with the pattern

```
\"{ascii}*\"        { SAVE_CTX; return STRING;}
```

I wonder if your use of `{ascii}{1}` is because you think that the `{1}` will somehow override the `+` in the expansion of `{ascii}`. (It won't.) Otherwise, I find the use of redundant `{1}` operators at various places in your flex patterns to be mysterious. For me, they're just visual noise which makes understanding the patterns harder, because `{1}` is just an identity operator.

Regardless of whether you expect `char` to match one or any number of "ascii" characters, you definitely want it to stop matching when you hit a <kbd>'</kbd> and similarly for the string pattern. You might also want to be able to use escape sequences, particularly (for example) `'\''` and `"Two lines\nwith \"quoted\" string"`.

(Also, do you really want to allow arbitrary control characters including NULs in a character string? If so, why arbitrarily exclude characters whose code values are greater than 127?)

Recognizing all possible escape sequences is work and I have no idea which sequences if any you want to handle, but basically you need patterns something like:

```
["]([\x00-\x7F]{-}["\\\n]|\\(.|\n))*["]
```

and (taking a wild guess as to your intentions):

```
[']([\x00-\x7F]{-}['\\\n]|\\([[:print:]]|[0-7]{1,3}|x[[:xdigit]]{2})[']
```

although as I said above, I'm reluctant to endorse `[\x00-\x7F]` and I use it only for illustration purposes, in particular to illustrate the flex-specific `{-}` operator.

---

A few final notes which have nothing to do with the question:

1. It's usually better to include a *minimal compilable* excerpt from your source files. Since SO is intended to be a permanent repository of questions and answer which may benefit other programmers with similar problems, possibly some years in the future, links to pastebin resources which are likely to expire are no very helpful.
2. Using `SAVE_CTX` liberally means that you will be unnecessarily calling `strdup()` on a lot of strings (op codes, for example) which you will then need to `free()`. I didn't look at your bison file because it was irrelevant to the problem, but in general I try to avoid passing copied strings to bison for tokens with a known (or canonical) representation, partly for the overhead of all the string copies, and partly because having to free all the strings adds unnecessary complication to every bison action. YMMV
3. Defining an end-of-file token other than the standard one is generally unnecessary and can cause obscure bugs. It's usually better to just let the scanner implement its default `<<EOF>>` rule, which will be recognized by bison-generated parsers as an end-of-file signal with the consequence that the parser will know that it should not attempt to read any more tokens.
4. Although `flex` lets you combine multiple patterns into a single action using the special action marker <kbd>|</kbd>, the patterns remain independent. Using the regular expression alternation operator (also written <kbd>|</kbd>) should normally be preferred because it produces scanners with smaller tables. So rather than:

   ```
   "xxx"          |
   ".xxx"         { /* some action */ }
   ```

   you should prefer

   ```
   "xxx"|".xxx"   { /* some action */ }
   ```

   or even

   ```
   [.]?"xxx"      { /* some action */ }
   ```

   This is particularly the case when the patterns are single characters and the action is to return the character; I always recommend using the single default rule:

   ```
   .              { return yytext[0]; }
   ```

   at the end of the grammar. That means the "invalid" characters will be passed to the parser as unknown token codes, which the parser will then reject with an error; that allows error-handling to be centralized in the parser instead of being spread between the parser and the scanner. It has the additional advantage of keeping the scanner and the parser in sync when new operators are added to the parser; the `flex` file doesn't need to be modified.

Comment: I can't say a word how you helped me! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: EOF rule was implemented due to some errors, as I now understand, was caused by bad ascii parsing